# How to move to a particular state on click of browser back without affecting ui-router state machine

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, back

I am creating a secured website (using AngularJS 1.3) where I want to redirect the user to 'Login' state if he clicks browser back button. I am using ui-router for state changes, and I make use stateChangeSuccess event and previousState property for other use cases. So, clearing out window history may not be an option if it clears out ui-router's previousState information also.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the stateChangeStart event? In that, you can check and redirect to login page.

Comment: Ya. But I do need to go to previous state if user clicks on the HTML back button provided in the page (which is present in only few of the pages). But he clicks browser back button in then I need to send him to Login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and i made a workaround like this:

You can use ui-router optional parameters:

https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider

An example:

```
$stateProvider.state('yourState', {
        url: "/url",
        templateUrl: 'yourTemplate',
        params: {
            click: {value: "false"}
        }
    }
)
```

In the ui-sref (my button), i use:

```
ui-sref="yourState({click: 'true'})"
```

After that you can use the $stateChangeStart to prevent go back or do whatever you want:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    if (toState.name === 'yourState') {
        if (toParams.click == 'false') {
            // DO YOUR THING
        }
    };
});
```

I know that is not a generic solution, but i think that you can adapt this to work with all your application (maybe regular expresions for the state name)